# Java - reduce Time-To-Live of UDP packet by sending it via MulticastSocket?

Tags: java, sockets, udp, multicast

I need to send a few UDP packets that will not reach their destination (time to live value is very small). I am working in Java and I don't want to go through the hassle to writing and compiling native code for Windows, Ubuntu, and Mac just to set the TTL values of a few packets. I noticed that java.net.MulticastSocket has a "set time to live" option and that it extends DatagramSocket. Can I just send my short lived packets through a MulticastSocket with a small TTL value instead of through a DatagramSocket even though the short lived packets are not being multi-cast? Will that work?

Comment: DatagramSocketImpl also has a time to live value, and the constructor for a DatagramSocket can take a DatagramSocketImpl ( http://download.java.net/jdk7/archive/b123/docs/api/java/net/DatagramSocketImpl.html ). See if that's viable?

Comment: I'm not going to implement the abstract class DatagramSocketImpl if MulticastSocket.setTimeToLive works for non-multicast packets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. It does NOT work for all packets. MulticastSocket.setTimeToLive(0) does not affect normal UDP traffic sent via a MulticastSocket - it only affects packets sent as part of a multicast.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it will work for all packets.

Comment: When I send a non-multicast packet from client to server after setting the TTL value to 0, the server still receives the packet, same as if the TTL were 64.